# $_GET - Hide the URL details

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

May I know if there is a way to hidden the `URL` or the full details on the `URL`. For example, I have a link that will show a details for a file report. For that link, I am using `GET`. Example as below,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#pr_id").change(function(){
        var pr_no = $('#pr_id').val();
        $.post('orderform.php',
        {
            pr_no : pr_no
        })
        .done(function(data){
            $('#result').html('<a href="../view-detail-purchase-pdf.php?pr_no='+ pr_no +'" class="popupwindow"');
            $(".popupwindow").popupwindow(profiles);    
        });
    }); 
});
```

Can I hide the `pr_no` on the link if using the `GET` method or if there is another option to do this. Can also provide me with a link or resource. Just for an info, I'm using a `popupwindow plugin` that will open the link in new window.

> **Update Code with POST**

I'm not sure whether I am doing it correctly. It does `POST` the value to the selected page as seen on the `Network Header` but it does not open the new page as requested. Below are the update of my codes;

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#pr_id").change(function(){
        var pr_no = $('#pr_id').val();
        $.post('orderform.php',
        {
            pr_no : pr_no
        })
        .done(function(data){
            $('#result').html('<a href="../view-detail-purchase-pdf.php?" class="popupwindow" id="newLink">' + pr_no + '</a>');
            $('#newLink').click(function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                var page = $(this).attr('href');
                $.post(page,
                {
                    pr_no : pr_no
                })
                .done(function(data){
                    var myWindow = window.open(page, "MsgWindow", "width=800,height=800");
                });
            });
        });
    }); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: No. The whole point of a GET request is that data is passed in the URL. If you want to 'hide' values, pass them through POST instead - but note they are still visible in the request body. If you're worried about data security you would need to employ some form of data encryption.

Comment: You can't have a client send a request without letting the client see the request.  You need to figure out what your security model is.  You may be looking for session state.

Comment: Why use a GET request? Sounds like you need to post a form to a new window.

Comment: You could "hide" it with `POST` or `COOKIE` the information will still be present (viewable by someone that knows what they are doing) and could be manipulated though.

Comment: Have you thought of using POST instead?

Comment: I tried using POST before this but it does not send the values. Probably there is a mistake that I made

Comment: If you for some reason need to use GET instead of POST and assuming you're just trying to hide from prying eyes and not someone with any degree of sophistication, base64_encode and base64_decode (on the server side) combined with btoa and atob (on the client side) should work.

You can learn about them at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102670/php-form-example-which-will-encrypt-query-string-get-data-hiding-rather-tha and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-a-string-to-base64-in-javascript

Comment: Make sure your PHP code is using the `$_POST` or `$_REQUEST` variables to get the passed values from the AJAX request. If you use `$_GET` when your AJAX is POSTing those variables will not exist in PHP.